# Multiple url query parameters and if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, url-parameters

I'm a beginner in PHP programming(or any other for that matter) and I'm facing a problem while trying to work on my first real world project.
I have two parameters in my url, category and item, I want to use them in an if condition like this, like if they're both there, display something:

```
if ($_GET["category"] && $_GET["item"]) {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Is this even possible? I have tested the parameter values with echo outside if/elseif statements and they work. Also, if I use a single query parameter with if statement, it works.

Thanks a lot for your time.
Regards.

P.S PHP version = 5.2.6.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? **Just try it** and find it out. Also you want to check if that element **is set** <- And that is also the function for it: `isset()`

Comment: It's possible but you should correct your code like `if (($_GET["category"]) && ($_GET["item"]))` but even better it would to check if the parameters are present. For example with `if (array_key_exists('category', $_GET) && (array_key_exists('item', $_GET))`

Comment: `isset($_GET['category'], $_GET['item'])`

Comment: @Rizier123
Well, I did add isset() but it just wouldn't work and query parameters are shown in the address bar.

Comment: @JSB there is no need to add extra parentheses, the code posted by Sam-R2D2 is correct.

Comment: @JSB
I'll try to test the "array_key_exists", kinda advanced for me at the moment but will give it a shot.

Comment: Upgrade your PHP to 5.5 or 5.6 if possible. PHP 5.2 is [dead and buried](http://php.net/eol.php).

Comment: @axiac If this syntax is correct and it's not working on my side, this maybe because of PHP 5.2.x. Although I'm not sure of that but I'll try to give newer version of php a shot as soon as possible.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have syntax errors. It compiles and runs on any PHP version. It triggers notices if your [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) configuration directive includes [`E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) but they doesn't stop the execution. But if the code doesn't have the outcome you expect, that's a different story. Read about [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) data type and [`logical operators`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, problem was somewhere else but I learned a couple other things from your answers
I was trying to use it with "elseif" with an if statement behind it and there was "category" in both of them so it didn't work. Conflicting code made it problematic.

Comment: @axiac There was missing a double quote behind item.

Comment: @JSB I copy-pasted the code from the question into a file and ran it. PHP didn't complain about anything and you can visually see there is no problem with that code. And the question was not edited.

Comment: Real reason was another if statement behind this statement. Let me try to elaborate:
if($_GET["category"].
And after this statement, I had this:
elseif($_GET["category"] && $_GET["item"].
I just changed the "category" in elseif statement to "category_of_item" and the problem was solved.  
P.S I gave it one and a half day before posting here. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest way to do this:

```
if (isset($_GET["category"],$_GET["item"]) && !empty($_GET["category"]) && !empty($_GET["item"])) {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: FYI `isset` can take multiple variables at once, and will return true only if all the variables are set.

Comment: True! I forget about that. I changed my answer :)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, problem was somewhere else but I learned a couple other things from your answers
I was trying to use it with "elseif" with an if statement behind it and there was "category" in both of them so it didn't work. Conflicting code made it problematic.

Answer (score 1):

your code need to be changed to

```
 if (isset($_GET["category"]) && isset($_GET["item"])){
   echo "Success"
 }
```

checking if empty will need `empty($_GET["category")` to be added